# Grails - Upgrade from 3.1.9 to 3.2.6

Tags: grails

I am trying to update application from grails 3.1.9 to 3.2.6 But I am getting this error when I run `grails run-app`.

```
| Error Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':profile'. Type 'gradle dependencies' for more information
```

The project compiles successfully but it give error on `run-app`.

I did `gradle dependencies` and found out that it failed to find profile dependencies

```
    profile
\--- :web: -> org.grails.profiles:web:3.2.6 FAILED
```

But when I refresh dependencies it is successful.

Comment: Looks like you need to set 3.2.5 version of profiles for grails 3.2.6.

Comment: yes i changed the version to 3.2.1

Comment: You shouldn't explicitly set the version. If you upgrade in the future you won't get the update to the profile automatically. The grails-bom should automatically pick the correct version depending on the grails version.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

when using profile dependency like this

`profile "org.grails.profiles:web"`

It will use grails version for this dependency like `3.2.6` so you need to explicitly set the version

`profile "org.grails.profiles:web:3.2.1"`

**Update**

This works when this error `Error:(19, 0) No service of type StyledTextOutputFactory available in ProjectScopeServices.` occurs in intellij. To solve this error we need to add this spring dependency plugin

```
id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "0.6.0.RELEASE"
```

but then the above issue occur which I posted as question. So the above solution works

Comment: That is not correct. It should use the version from the grails-bom which may or may not be the same as the grails version